# Set the position of DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm showing the following `<div>` conditionally in a JSP page:

```
<div id="error_message">Wrong nickname or password!</div>
```

The style of the DIV defined as follows:

```
div#error_message{
    width: 200px;
    left: 400px;
    top: 400px;
}
```

However, it appears at left 0 and top 0 instead of left 400px and top 400px. What am I doing wrong? How do I make the `<div>` to appear in the middle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give it a `position` other than `static` (the default) for `top` and `left` to have an effect, for example:

```
div#error_message{
  width: 200px;
  left: 400px;
  top: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: @Andriy - what is the issue, that it's not showing at all, or that it's in the wrong position?

Comment: @Andriy - That shouldn't be the case with what you posted, you can test it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fMPS9/  do you have *other* CSS affecting it?

Comment: In normal HTML works fine, but doing out.print () in JSP it does appear on 0.0
No, I have one css file

Comment: @Andriy - where are you printing it? Look at the source to see where it ends up in the page, if it's after `</html>` then yes you'll have issues...invalid HTML is unpredictable.

Comment: the DIV appears between the tabs <body> and </ body>

Comment: @Andriy - If you have a page I can access I'll take a look...but everything in your question/this answer works, there's something *else* in play here, I'd have to see it absent any other information to debug it.

Comment: The project is not on the web. So if I'll send it by email?

I'm noticing a problem: if I do "instpect" other DIVs of the page, "Matched css rules" appear exactly as they are in the css file, if I "inspect" the DIV of the error message on "Matched css rules"  appears only:
div {
display: block;
}

Comment: Okay, I found a solution! Thanks for help.
Solution was:
out.print ("<div style=\"position:relative; left:20px; top:50px\">Wrong  nickname or password </ div> ");
perhaps from JSP it could not connect to the css file

Comment: *"perhaps from JSP it could not connect to the css file"* - if that is the case, then your web browser's error console / debugger should be reporting a 404 (or whatever) for the CSS link.